# Combined display of EditText for Query with JSON Result to be able to scroll it

Tags: arrays, json, android-edittext, scrollview

Need advice on how to define screen to be able to scroll the result of the json , as attached :

> ```
> package com.lm.vciwhereabout;
>
>
> import java.util.ArrayList;
>
> import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
> import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
> import org.json.JSONArray;
> import org.json.JSONException;
> import org.json.JSONObject;
>
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.app.ListActivity;
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.os.StrictMode;
> import android.util.Log;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.widget.AdapterView;
> import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
> import android.widget.Button;
> import android.widget.EditText;
> import android.widget.ListAdapter;
> import android.widget.ListView;
> import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
> import android.widget.TextView;
> import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
>
>   public class querynameentry3 extends ListActivity {
>        EditText username;   // To take username as input from user
>        Button submit;    
>        TextView tv;      // TextView to show the result of MySQL query 
>
>        String returnString;   // to store the result of MySQL query after decoding JSON
>
>           /** Called when the activity is first created. */
>           public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
>         {
>            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
>         .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() // StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network
> ```
>
> access on the application's main thread
>               .penaltyLog().build());
>                     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>                     setContentView(R.layout.activity_jsonuse);
>
> ```
>               setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
>                       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1));
>
>               username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtxUsername);
>               submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);
>               tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showresult);
>
>               // define the action when user clicks on submit button
>               submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
>               {        
>                public void onClick(View v) 
>                {
>                 // declare parameters that are passed to PHP script i.e. the name "username" and its value submitted by user   
>                 ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
>
>                 // define the parameter
>                 postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",
>             username.getText().toString()));
>                 String response = null;
>
>                 // call executeHttpPost method passing necessary parameters 
>                 try 
>                 {
>            response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
>              "http://192.168.0.245/vciwhereabout/waboutbyuser.php", // your ip address if using localhost server
>              postParameters);
>
>            // store the result returned by PHP script that runs MySQL query
>            String result = response.toString();  
>
>             //parse json data
>
>                try{
>                        returnString = "";
>                  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
>                        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
>                                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
>                                Log.i("log_tag","post_id: "+json_data.getInt("post_id")+
>
>                                        ", username: "+json_data.getString("username")+
>                                        ", fdate: "+json_data.getString("fdate")+
>                                        ", tdate: "+json_data.getString("tdate")+
>                                        ", ftime: "+json_data.getString("ftime")+
>                                        ", ttime: "+json_data.getString("ttime")+
>                                        ", custbranch: "+json_data.getString("custbranch")+
>                                        ", custname: "+json_data.getString("custname")+
>                                        ", custaddr: "+json_data.getString("custaddr")+
>                                        ", custcity: "+json_data.getString("custcity")+
>                                        ", note: "+json_data.getString("note")
>                                );
>
>                                //Get an output to the screen
>
>                                returnString += "Username  :" + json_data.getString("username")
>                                    + "\n" + "From Date :" + json_data.getString("fdate") 
>                                + "\n" + "To Date     :" + json_data.getString("tdate") 
>                                + "\n" + "From Time :" + json_data.getString("ftime") 
>                                + "\n" + "To Time     :" + json_data.getString("ttime") 
>                                + "\n" + "Cust/Branch :" + json_data.getString("custbranch") 
>                                + "\n" + "Name        :" + json_data.getString("custname") 
>                                + "\n" + "Address    :" + json_data.getString("custaddr") 
>                                + "\n" + "City           :" + json_data.getString("custcity")
>                                + "\n" + "Note          :" + json_data.getString("note") + "\n"
>                                + "-------------------------------------------"  ;
>
>                                                            }
>                    }
>                catch(JSONException e){
>                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
>                                       }
>
>                try{
>                 tv.setText(returnString);
>                    }
>                catch(Exception e){
>                 Log.e("log_tag","Error in Display!" + e.toString());;          
>                                   }   
>                }
>                 catch (Exception e) {
>            Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());     
>                                      }
>                }         
>               });
>           }
>
>           private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter) {
>               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>           }
>
>       }
> ```

And this is the layout activity_jsonuse.xml :

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
>     android:text="Staff Name to be Query" />
>
>
> <EditText
>     android:id="@+id/edtxusername"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:inputType="text" >        
> </EditText>
>
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/submit"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="Submit"
>     android:layout_gravity="center"
>      />
>
>     <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/showresult"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
>     android:text="Result" />
>
>   <ListView
>     android:id="@android:id/list"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>      />          </LinearLayout>
> ```

On make the output to the screen, how do I defined it / changed it, so I can scroll the results ?

Since I have already define the layout for the query with edittext, could I make or call the new layout to just display the result with the scroll capability ( in one .java activities) ? Please help guide me on my code above.

Thanks a lot (I'm new on Android and Programming).

With addition of the scrollview as attached , solved. But the virtual keyboard still appear after displaying the result. How to removed the virtual keyboard automatically, after result appeared on screen ? Thanks.

> 

```
<ScrollView
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:lines="20"
>     android:layout_height="390dip" >        
>            <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/showresult2"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:singleLine="false"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
>   
>         android:paddingBottom="2dip"
>         android:paddingLeft="45dip"
>         android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
>        
>         />
>   
>            </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the addition of the scrollview as attched, solved my problem.

```
<ScrollView
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:lines="20"
>     android:layout_height="390dip" >        
>            <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/showresult2"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:singleLine="false"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
>   
>         android:paddingBottom="2dip"
>         android:paddingLeft="45dip"
>         android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
>        
>         />
>   
>            </ScrollVi
```

ew>